# How to implement left outer join linq dynamic (linq.dynamic.core)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I am trying to get left outer join working with linq dynamic,
The ideas I got is that I need to use group join with select many,
So, I think I need to translate the following example to linq dynamic but I cannot get the syntax right

please help translating this linq code to Dynamic Linq

```
db.Categories    
  .GroupJoin(db.Products,
      Category => Category.CategoryId,
      Product => Product.CategoryId,
      (x, y) => new { Category = x, Products = y })
  .SelectMany(
      xy => xy.Products.DefaultIfEmpty(),
      (x, y) => new { Category = x.Category, Product = y })
  .Select(s => new
  {
      CategoryName = s.Category.Name,     
      ProductName = s.Product.Name   
  });
```

Thanks

Comment: Create/use navigation properties and forget about joins.

Comment: Thanks unfortunately the two tables are not in a relationship so it is not an option as far as I know

Comment: Does your linq work with in-memory tables?

Comment: This linq works fine and produce left outer join result, it can be simplified as linq, but I put this GroupJoin + SelectMany format  because eveybody says this is the only way it can work with Dynamic Linq, yet did not find a proper example on how to do it with Dynamic Linq